# Add Icon to MenuItem for a QML SystemTrayIcon Menu

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

In `QML` using `QtQuick 2`, it seems to be very easy to add icons to `MenuItems` in a `Menu`, [according to the Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qt-labs-platform-menuitem.html). But when doing this for a `MenuItem` in a `SystemTrayIcon`, nothing happens.

This code produces a context menu for the `SystemTrayIcon`, but no icons are added to the context menu. How can this be achieved?

```
Window {
    /*...*/
    SystemTrayIcon {
        visible: true
        id: systrayicon
        icon.name: "my-application"

        menu: Menu {
            title: "My Application"
            
            data: [
                MenuItem {
                    id: quit
                    text: qsTr("&Quit")
                    icon.name: 'window-close'
                    onTriggered: Qt.exit(0)
                },
                MenuItem {
                    id: play
                    text: qsTr("&Play")
                    icon.name: "media-playback-play"
                    onTriggered: dbus.send("Play")
                },
                MenuItem {
                    id: next
                    text: qsTr("&Edit")
                    icon.name: "kwrite"
                    onTriggered: app.edit()
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The expected results are that the `MenuItems` have an icon each. But none of them do. This application is built with qmake/make under Linux using Qt 6.4.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably provide your icons as PNGs in your project and use `icon.source` to set the icons. `icon.name` is heavily relying on the OS supporting those icons.

Have a look at the [icon.name](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-abstractbutton.html#icon.name-prop) documentation. There are further links to understand the names better in [QIcon::fromTheme(const QStrin &name)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qicon.html#fromTheme) like this one http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html

I'm using Qt 6.4.0, Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS with Xfce 4.16.3 and adapting your demo a bit shows the icon as seen in the gif below.

```
import QtQuick
import Qt.labs.platform

Window {
    title: "SystemTrayIcon"
    width: 320
    height: 240
    visible: true

    SystemTrayIcon {
        visible: true
        id: systrayicon
        icon.name: "applications-multimedia"

        menu: Menu {
            title: "My Application"

            data: [
                MenuItem {
                    id: quit
                    text: qsTr("&Quit")
                    icon.name: 'application-exit'
                    onTriggered: Qt.exit(0)
                },
                MenuItem {
                    id: play
                    text: qsTr("&Play")
                    icon.name: "media-playback-start"
                    onTriggered: dbus.send("Play")
                },
                MenuItem {
                    id: next
                    text: qsTr("&Edit")
                    icon.name: "accessories-text-editor"
                    onTriggered: app.edit()
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: So, most likely this is an issue with my environment. I tried your exact code on Arch Linux under plasma/kde, but no icons are painted. I think I'll try bundle a local icon package via qrc/index.theme